# Netmiko - handling confirmation from Cisco

Tags: networking, python, automation

I just start using netmiko and have a problem with one script. The script should delete a user and create another one in Cisco device. The problem that I have is with confirmation in configuration mode I don`t know how to handle it. I send this command to cisco

```
ssh.send_config_set('no username admin')
```

and the device is waiting to press enter.

```
R1#no username admin

This operation will remove all username related configurations with same name.Do you want to continue? [confirm]
```

Thank you.

Comment: So why don't you press Enter?

Comment: He wants the script to also interpret the output or needs to figure out a way to respond by assuming what the preceding command may be?